# Store my chats in Appcelerator cloud service

Tags: titanium

I am working on a chat app in Titanium .I need to store my chats in Cloud server provided by appcelerator(ACS). Can anybody give some idea about it .

Suggestions are always appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading the manual. There's an API specifically for Chat.

http://cloud.appcelerator.com/docs/api/v1/chats/create